# Docker entrypoint script to perform installation

Tags: docker, shell

I'm trying to build a container that runs a linux application.

I started with an ubuntu base image and the entrypoint script performs the application install on boot only if the application folder not exists.

My problem is related to the application install, because the install script requires user input to specify sono infomration.

I tried to create a file with the answer:

```
cat <<EOF >/usr/local/bin/config.conf
yes
yes
y
EOF
```

and pass it to the script

```
/install < /usr/local/bin/config.conf
```

or pass the answers directly to the script

```
/install << EOF
y
y
y
EOF
```

but the answer are not interpreted by the script.

Is there a bettwer way?

I prefear to not modify the install script.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why you want to install application after container startup, can't you just add application installation inside dockerfile, so that your docker image itself has the application installed.

Comment: @mchawre, this is the other thing i want to do. I really new to docker image build. I looking for the best practice to create a docker image.
The application is installed with a bash script.

Comment: Then this would be a great place to get started. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ Try to understand how to package your application inside docker and accordingly proceed further.

Comment: From dockerfile (good) or at container start as now, you will get the same problem with your interactive install script. The only good solution I know to handle that is [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). Here is the [first tutorial that poped-out in a search result](https://www.slashroot.in/expect-command-tutorial-linux-example-usage). You can find others.